# Drap and drop GUI PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

guys I have a question, i have a code and I want to apply these changes to it but it goes wrong or doesn't work with the methods I have in my knowledge, i have a simple GUI where these are 3 icons in the left side and a graphical view on the right side that is meant to accept the items, it works fine already but the changes I would like to make are:

```
1\.when moving the icon instances the X and Y coordinates of them be printed in the code terminal

2\.when left-clicking on the icon instances that we already dropped, an empty widget opens that stays open until we close it

3\.when right-clicking on them a Q menu with a bunch of options shows up. save, edit, delete.
```

the problem with my code is that it applies those changes to the fixed items on the left side, not the ones that I want:

here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QMainWindow, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QToolButton, QMenu, QAction, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QDrag, QCursor
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QMimeData

class DraggableIcon(QToolButton):
    def __init__(self, icon_path, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setIcon(QIcon(icon_path))
        self.setIconSize(QSize(64, 64))
        self.setFixedSize(64, 64)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True) 
        self.icon_path = icon_path

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # Left-click: Open an empty widget
            self.openEmptyWidget()
        elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            # Right-click: Show context menu
            self.showContextMenu(event)

    def openEmptyWidget(self):
        empty_widget = QDialog()
        empty_widget.setWindowTitle("Empty Widget")
        empty_widget.exec_()

    def showContextMenu(self, event):
        menu = QMenu()
        save_action = QAction("Save")
        edit_action = QAction("Edit")
        delete_action = QAction("Delete")
        
        menu.addAction(save_action)
        menu.addAction(edit_action)
        menu.addAction(delete_action)
        
        action = menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))

class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, scene):
        super().__init__(scene)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        mime_data = event.mimeData()
        if mime_data.hasText():
            icon_path = mime_data.text()
            pixmap = QPixmap(icon_path)
            icon_item = self.scene().addPixmap(pixmap)
            
            # Get the scene position where the drop occurred
            scene_pos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
            icon_item.setPos(scene_pos)
            
            # Make the item movable
            icon_item.setFlag(QGraphicsPixmapItem.ItemIsMovable)
            
            # Change cursor shape to a hand
            icon_item.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))

            event.acceptProposedAction()

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Drag and drop")

        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        main_layout = QHBoxLayout(central_widget)

        icon_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Here we create Draggable Icon instances
        self.icons = ["athena_icon.png", "poseidon_icon.png", "ares_icon.png"]
        for icon_path in self.icons:
            icon_button = DraggableIcon(icon_path)
            icon_button.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))  # Set cursor for the icons
            icon_layout.addWidget(icon_button)

        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        graphics_view = MyGraphicsView(scene)
        scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 800, 800)  # Set the scene rect
        scene.setItemIndexMethod(QGraphicsScene.NoIndex)  # Optimize for static scenes
        
        main_layout.addLayout(icon_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(graphics_view)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.resize(800, 800)  # We set the initial size
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**_ __ _**_ **_**